# What is this card game called

Tags: identify-this-game

Each player is dealt 4 cards, and 4 cards are dealt, face up onto the table. The deck is placed on the table face down.

One deck of cards, containing three jokers

Jokers = 25 points
Face cards = 10 points
Number cards = 1 point

On their turn, Each player draws a card and sees if they have a card in their hand that matches one of the face up cards on the table, if they do, they can take the card from the table, add it to the one in their hand and place them in front of them, face up, then they draw another card from the deck and keep playing until they either decide to stop, or cannot match any more cards. They must then discard a card so they end their turn with four cards still in their hand.

The next player draws and plays, either matching cards in their hand to the ones on the table, as outlined above, or stealing from their opponents, but you can only steal the group of cards on the very top of the opponents individual piles.

Once a player has all four cards (i.e. 4 x jacks or 4 x 7's), their deck is safe as no one can steal underneath these cards.

The winner is the player at the end with the most points.

There may be additional rules to this game, which is why I am posting, any help as to the rules would be greatly appreciated.